# How can I use the pub `usage` library for analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, dart

So normally, I use this little script for analytics:

```
<script>
  window.ga = window.ga || function () {
        (ga.q = ga.q || []).push(arguments)
      };
  ga.l = +new Date;
  ga('create', 'UA-40648110-5', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async type="text/javascript"
        src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
```

But since I use Dart, I was looking for a Dart library for sending my information to analytics.

This package seems promising: https://github.com/dart-lang/usage But I find it hard to figure out, how I can use `usage` too basically do the same as my little javascript above.

So for a start I created this object:

`final ga = new AnalyticsHtml('UA-40648110-5', 'math_edit', '0.1.0');`

And now I'm searching for something that registers a pageview. I couldn't find that method, but I though this may be the equivalent:

`ga.sendScreenView('')`

However, it doesn't registers any pageview for me in google analytics. What do I do wrong?

I was also looking at: https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/googleapis/0.21.0/googleapis.analytics.v3/googleapis.analytics.v3-library.html

But I couldn't find any `ga` function in that package or any other documentation how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code it looks like `pageview` is not supported for now (see https://github.com/dart-lang/usage/blob/088caabf665b8873fa53c0a3ddee385ceec52c46/lib/src/usage_impl.dart#L177-L179 and usages of `_sendPayload`). You can try to submit a pull request to handle it.